# Get Simulink to make lines between components the shortest distance/untangle Simulink mess

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am new to simulink. I made the mistake of "left aligning" about 15 components in Simulink. Now they're all siting on top of eachother and when I moved them apart, their wires look sooo tangled up. So, I can't seem to find a way to get the blocks to all line up ingengiously (is there a way to do this?) so my next best thing would be to get the lines to be the shortest possible distance so I can actually see what's going on. Btw, diagram-->format-->any option, doesn't fix it. What should I do?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TPHAplo.gif

Comment: lol um so i guess theres no way to do that/untangle stuff other than by hand?

Comment: Yup..... Can't say for sure unless we see a snapshot of what you drew.

Answer (score 0):

Ok) 
First of all - you can use `Bus Creator` and `Bus Selector` blocks to combine signals. it's really useful. 
And one more useful thing - right click at any wire and choose option `Highlight signal to Source` or `Highlight signal to Destination`.
Try this!